# Reading user input with AUTOIT and pass to php

Tags: php, mysql, windows, autoit

I`m building a very simple login window with autoit, the user just type username and password.

How can I read a username and password input inside AUTOIT, and pass those values/parameters to PHP so the PHP can check inside the mysql .

Answer (score 4):

You can read the values from an input box using `GuiCtrlRead($INPUT_NAME)` and you can pass it to PHP with `_InetGetSource("http://yourwebsite.com/yourscript/file.php?name=" & GuiCtrlRead($INPUT_NAME) & "&password=" & GuiCtrlRead($INPUT_PASSWORD))`

Comment: Thanks, I just realize I did not check any of my older questions, LOL.. Anyway, can you please give me a quick simple example of the PHP that will receive the parameters? or any link about it?

Comment: @massaki you can just use the PHP [_GET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) variable.

Comment: @ massaki Alright, but you have to change the variables ofcourse.

Comment: @massaki let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2527/discussion-between-devator-and-massaki)

Comment: Ok so , I`m trying to pass the parameters with the _InetGetSource, but it`s nor really working... how can I change it just for test? instead $input_name can I replace for the parameter itself?

Comment: I`m trying to use the chat with you, anyway, I changed the variables of course, and it seem the autoit is not corrrectly sending the variables with the _InetGetSource as post method.... how can I change the _InetGetSource line with the variables itself to be sure? e.x instead & $INPUT_NAME   can I use the Username itself?  
Also, what is the & means? I can`t find information about using the InetGetSource with post method